# R package Error: 'encode_colour' is not an exported object from 'namespace:farver'

Tags: r, error-handling

I've run the bellow codes:
`kaplan.meier <-
    survfit(Surv(TimePrev, event=use) ~ Subpage, data=inuse.surv)
autoplot(kaplan.meier, xlim=c(0, 30))`

But got an error: 
`Error: 'encode_colour' is not an exported object from 'namespace:farver'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ... and might I suggest you remove the "enter code here" blocks. (It does look odd, though, since that function is *supposed* to be exported, per https://github.com/thomasp85/farver/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L9.)

Comment: When you edit your question, it may also be informative to give us a little more information about your system versions and such. Please include the output from either `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` (not both), preferably in a code block.

Comment: Thanks! I removed farver package manually and update the version. Next time I will post the version info!